# Error with SQL Server profiler

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I am having a strange problem with SQL Server Profiler. We have a .NET program running and collecting traces every hour and dumping into a central database.

In a few instances, I see that the trace is closing, but not deleting the file (in original folder) and moving to the archives folder.

```
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0 
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2
```

The above two commands are running most of the time, but when the first command fails, it's a problem to run `renamefiles.cmd`.

I have to manually stop the trace and delete the files manually again and start the trace back.

Contents of `renamefiles.cmd`:

```
@ECHO OFF
if '%1' == '' goto usage
if '%2' == '' goto usage
if '%3' == '' goto usage

set fileDes= "D:\Audit\archives\%1%"
set fileSource="D:\Audit\%1%"
ECHO %fileDes%

COPY /Y /B %fileSource%  %fileDes%

if '%3' == '1'  goto dbchange
if '%3' == '2'  goto WRchange
:dbchange
ren %fileDes%  DBaudit_%2%.trc
del %fileSource%
goto done

:WRchange
ren %fileDes%  WR_DBaudit_%2%.trc
del %fileSource%
goto done




REM: How to use screen
:usage
echo.
echo Usage: MyScript Server Environment
echo file: file source to copy
echo timestamp: time stamp
echo.
echo Example: MyScript.cmd filesource timestamp tracetype
echo.
echo.
goto done

:done
```

Comment: Why attempt to copy the active trace file after the trace stop fails? Consider using `MOVE` instead of `COPY`, `REN`, and `DEL`.

Comment: A few batch script things I wanted to point out, ensure the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd arguments are just `%1`, `%2`, or `%3` only just like that. In the `:WRchange` and `:dbchange` routines, do a `CD /D "D:\Audit\archives"` on the first line. Then for the delete line use `IF EXIST "%fileSource%" del /Q /F "%fileSource%"`... maybe that'll help but easy enough to test.

Comment: Consider testing with `IF EXIST "%fileSource%" COPY /Y /B "%fileSource%"  "%fileDes%"` as well but if the `/B` switch isn't absolutely needed you might look into `IF EXIST "%fileSource%" XCOPY /Y /F "%fileSource%"  "D:\Audit\"` instead of how you have the `COPY` command syntax.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response magicallydelicious.
I am confused with the recommendations you provided
Can you please provide more information or specific. Thank you